# Fastlane scan launches a new test session while current test session is not finished

Tags: ios, unit-testing, continuous-integration, fastlane, quick-nimble

I have some test cases failing due to a new test session started during this test case execution. This makes the current test case crashing.
As you can see in the provided logs, there is a first test session launched:

```
[16:42:35]: ▸ 2019-10-22 16:42:35.341 xcodebuild[91170:10223499] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (BA6E9994-B774-43D3-A58C-DBD1AB068B48) Beginning test session ProjectExampleTests-BA6E9994-B774-43D3-A58C-DBD1AB068B48 at 2019-10-22 16:42:35.340 with Xcode 10E1001 on target <DVTiPhoneSimulator: 0x7fdf07a8f0f0> {
[16:42:35]: ▸       SimDevice: iPhone 5s iOS 9.0 (4353112F-6BFA-4DD4-AE7A-5E772AB438D5, iOS 9.0, Shutdown)
[16:42:35]: ▸ } (9.0 (13A344))
```

Then while the test cases are not all executed yet, another session is started on the same simulator, making the current test case failing:

```
[16:43:15]: ▸ 2019-10-22 16:43:15.243 xcodebuild[91170:10223499] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (7BC2DA5F-0765-4705-83F0-D2F215E7F2ED) Beginning test session ProjectExampleTests-7BC2DA5F-0765-4705-83F0-D2F215E7F2ED at 2019-10-22 16:43:15.244 with Xcode 10E1001 on target <DVTiPhoneSimulator: 0x7fdf07a8f0f0> {
[16:43:15]: ▸       SimDevice: iPhone 5s iOS 9.0 (4353112F-6BFA-4DD4-AE7A-5E772AB438D5, iOS 9.0, Booted)
[16:43:15]: ▸ } (9.0 (13A344))
[16:43:15]: ▸ 2019-10-22 16:43:15.247 xcodebuild[91170:10223499] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (7BC2DA5F-0765-4705-83F0-D2F215E7F2ED) Finished requesting crash reports. Continuing with testing.
[16:43:16]: ▸     ✗ bridges_ProjectExample_Badge_set, Test crashed
```

I already checked that I have only 1 simulator matching each simulator name provided in the command.
Also I set `max_concurrent_simulators` to 1 and `disable_concurrent_testing` to true but this doesn't help solving this issue.
Is this due to a missing configuration?
Thanks.

**Complete output when running fastlane**

```
[16:41:32]: ------------------------------
[16:41:32]: --- Step: default_platform ---
[16:41:32]: ------------------------------
[16:41:33]: Driving the lane 'ios unit_tests' 
[16:41:33]: --------------------------------
[16:41:33]: --- Step: clear_derived_data ---
[16:41:33]: --------------------------------
[16:41:33]: Derived Data path located at: /Users/claude/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
[16:41:34]: Successfully cleared Derived Data ♻️
[16:41:34]: ------------------
[16:41:34]: --- Step: scan ---
[16:41:34]: ------------------
[16:41:34]: $ xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -workspace ./ProjectExample.xcworkspace -scheme ProjectExampleTests
[16:41:36]: $ xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -workspace ./ProjectExample.xcworkspace -scheme ProjectExampleTests

+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                            Summary for scan 2.134.0                                                            |
+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| scheme                                         | ProjectExampleTests                                                                           |
| devices                                        | ["iPhone 5s iOS 9.0", "iPhone 6s iOS 10.3", "iPhone X iOS 12.2"]                              |
| skip_build                                     | true                                                                                          |
| disable_concurrent_testing                     | true                                                                                          |
| prelaunch_simulator                            | true                                                                                          |
| max_concurrent_simulators                      | 1                                                                                             |
| workspace                                      | ./ProjectExample.xcworkspace                                                                  |
| derived_data_path                              | /Users/claude/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectExample-hkcobndhrmxnnkbkrtfhglxkvvbm |
| skip_detect_devices                            | false                                                                                         |
| force_quit_simulator                           | false                                                                                         |
| reset_simulator                                | false                                                                                         |
| reinstall_app                                  | false                                                                                         |
| clean                                          | false                                                                                         |
| open_report                                    | false                                                                                         |
| output_directory                               | ./fastlane/test_output                                                                        |
| output_types                                   | html,junit                                                                                    |
| buildlog_path                                  | ~/Library/Logs/scan                                                                           |
| include_simulator_logs                         | false                                                                                         |
| should_zip_build_products                      | false                                                                                         |
| result_bundle                                  | false                                                                                         |
| use_clang_report_name                          | false                                                                                         |
| slack_use_webhook_configured_username_and_icon | false                                                                                         |
| slack_username                                 | fastlane                                                                                      |
| slack_icon_url                                 | https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/fastlane.tools/fastlane.png                                |
| skip_slack                                     | false                                                                                         |
| slack_only_on_failure                          | false                                                                                         |
| xcodebuild_command                             | env NSUnbufferedIO=YES xcodebuild                                                             |
| fail_build                                     | true                                                                                          |
| xcode_path                                     | /Applications/Xcode.app                                                                       |
+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

[16:41:38]: $ set -o pipefail && env NSUnbufferedIO=YES xcodebuild -workspace ./ProjectExample.xcworkspace -scheme ProjectExampleTests -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=4353112F-6BFA-4DD4-AE7A-5E772AB438D5' -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=B2AD710C-3F80-4A5E-B02B-A72DE36B787A' -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=CBD79494-ADD4-404D-AA94-87BF758EA8D3' -derivedDataPath '/Users/claude/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectExample-hkcobndhrmxnnkbkrtfhglxkvvbm' -maximum-concurrent-test-simulator-destinations 1 -disable-concurrent-testing test | tee '/Users/claude/Library/Logs/scan/ProjectExampleTests-ProjectExampleTests.log' | xcpretty  --report html --output '/Users/claude/Dev/ProjectExample/fastlane/test_output/report.html' --report junit --output '/Users/claude/Dev/ProjectExample/fastlane/test_output/report.junit' --report junit --output '/var/folders/m7/y78wyb0n2rqf74b98_rc1rbr0000gn/T/junit_report20191022-91121-r6mvwk' 



...



[16:42:35]: Running Tests: ▸ Touching ProjectExampleTests.xctest
[16:42:35]: ▸ Signing /Users/claude/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectExample-hkcobndhrmxnnkbkrtfhglxkvvbm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectExampleTests.xctest
[16:42:35]: ▸ 2019-10-22 16:42:35.340 xcodebuild[91170:10223615]  IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: Writing diagnostic log for test session to:
[16:42:35]: ▸ /Users/claude/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectExample-hkcobndhrmxnnkbkrtfhglxkvvbm/Logs/Test/Test-ProjectExampleTests-2019.10.22_16-41-41-+0200.xcresult/1_Test/Diagnostics/ProjectExampleTests-27FC4C1D-77D3-45BC-BC16-B20769DB5E27/ProjectExampleTests-CEB88879-DFF1-4E64-839E-D4625B7BA4C0/Session-ProjectExampleTests-2019-10-22_164235-Msfqlj.log
[16:42:35]: ▸ 2019-10-22 16:42:35.341 xcodebuild[91170:10223499] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (BA6E9994-B774-43D3-A58C-DBD1AB068B48) Beginning test session ProjectExampleTests-BA6E9994-B774-43D3-A58C-DBD1AB068B48 at 2019-10-22 16:42:35.340 with Xcode 10E1001 on target <DVTiPhoneSimulator: 0x7fdf07a8f0f0> {
[16:42:35]: ▸       SimDevice: iPhone 5s iOS 9.0 (4353112F-6BFA-4DD4-AE7A-5E772AB438D5, iOS 9.0, Shutdown)
[16:42:35]: ▸ } (9.0 (13A344))
[16:42:45]: ▸ 2019-10-22 16:42:45.014 xcodebuild[91170:10223499] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (BA6E9994-B774-43D3-A58C-DBD1AB068B48) Finished requesting crash reports. Continuing with testing.
[16:42:47]: ▸ All tests
[16:42:47]: ▸ Test Suite ProjectExampleTests.xctest started



...


[16:43:15]: ▸ 2019-10-22 16:43:15.243 xcodebuild[91170:10226022]  IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: Writing diagnostic log for test session to:
[16:43:15]: ▸ /Users/claude/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectExample-hkcobndhrmxnnkbkrtfhglxkvvbm/Logs/Test/Test-ProjectExampleTests-2019.10.22_16-41-41-+0200.xcresult/1_Test/Diagnostics/ProjectExampleTests-27FC4C1D-77D3-45BC-BC16-B20769DB5E27/ProjectExampleTests-CEB88879-DFF1-4E64-839E-D4625B7BA4C0/Session-ProjectExampleTests-2019-10-22_164315-GhePTp.log
[16:43:15]: ▸ 2019-10-22 16:43:15.243 xcodebuild[91170:10223499] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (7BC2DA5F-0765-4705-83F0-D2F215E7F2ED) Beginning test session ProjectExampleTests-7BC2DA5F-0765-4705-83F0-D2F215E7F2ED at 2019-10-22 16:43:15.244 with Xcode 10E1001 on target <DVTiPhoneSimulator: 0x7fdf07a8f0f0> {
[16:43:15]: ▸       SimDevice: iPhone 5s iOS 9.0 (4353112F-6BFA-4DD4-AE7A-5E772AB438D5, iOS 9.0, Booted)
[16:43:15]: ▸ } (9.0 (13A344))
[16:43:15]: ▸ 2019-10-22 16:43:15.247 xcodebuild[91170:10223499] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (7BC2DA5F-0765-4705-83F0-D2F215E7F2ED) Finished requesting crash reports. Continuing with testing.
[16:43:16]: ▸     ✗ bridges_ProjectExample_Badge_set, Test crashed
[16:43:16]: ▸ Selected tests
[16:43:16]: ▸ Test Suite ProjectExampleTests.xctest started</pre>
```

#### Code

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do

  desc "build and launch unit tests"
  lane :unit_tests do
    run_unit_tests
  end

  def run_unit_tests
    clear_derived_data
    run_tests(scheme: "ProjectExampleTests",
              devices: ["iPhone 5s iOS 9.0", "iPhone 6s iOS 10.3", "iPhone X iOS 12.2"],
              skip_build: true,
              disable_concurrent_testing: true,
              prelaunch_simulator: true,
              max_concurrent_simulators: 1,
              slack_url: "https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxx")
  end

end
```

Comment: have you been able to solve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no. For now we have set "devices" to only one device and now we don't have the new test session launched, so tests are passing.